# How to use ORDER BY in a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

I have the following code:

```
use Northwind
go

create procedure CalcStatistics
    @year int = 0
as

if exists 
    (select * from sysobjects
  where name = 'Statistics' and type = 'U') 
  drop table Statistics

select      YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate) As [Year],
            DATEPART(qq, OrderDate) As [Q],
            SUM (Freight) As [Freight],
into        Statistics
from        ORDERS, ORDERDETAILS
where       ORDERS.OrderID = ORDERDETAILS.OrderID
AND         YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate) = @year
group by    YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate),
            DATEPART(qq, OrderDate)
order by    YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate)

exec CalcStatistics 1997
    select *
    from Statistics
```

I would like to make it so that the query prints the year and quarter of that year in ascending order, but when I try the old fashioned "order by DATEPART(qq, OrderDate)" it doesn't seem to affect the outcome of the query. How do I solve this, and why does my method not work?

Comment: If you replace the `order by` clause, then it should change the ordering.

Comment: Are you replacing 'order by    YEAR(ORDERS.OrderDate)' with 'order by DATEPART(qq, OrderDate)'? Or adding it to your 'order by' clause? Because you need both...

Comment: I tried inputting both order by and group by clauses to the code, it didn't change the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to make it so that the query prints the year and quarter of that year in ascending order,

Based on this statement, you need two keys in the `ORDER BY`.  One method uses the aliases, instead of the expressions.  This is simpler:

```
order by [Year], [Q]
```

Another trick when using dates is to order by the `MIN()` (or `MAX()`) of the dates:

```
order by MIN(ORDERS.OrderDate)
```

EDIT:

I think I see the problem.  You are putting this data into a table called `statistics`, not looking at the results from the query itself.  Then you are presumably running a query like this:

```
select s.*
from statistics s;
```

If so, the results are not in order.  The results from a SQL query are *unordered* unless the *query* specifies the ordering.  So:

```
select s.*
from statistics s
order by [Year], [Q];
```

Comment: This does not work. It still displays the quarters of 1997 in the wrong order

Comment: @TheYaeger . . . Edit your question and provide information on the the correct order.  This should be doing exactly what the quoted statement from the OP asks for.